# Use adb command in a Mac app

Tags: android, macos, terminal

I want to use `adb` command in a MAC app

I am **able** to use adb commands in **Terminal**, in my **Shell Scripts** as well. 
I am **able** to use the same in the **Services** that I create with Automator, even in **Applescripts**.

I am unable to use the adb command **ONLY** in any APP that I create using Automator. My App has a **workflow that runs shell script**. I am unable to use `adb devices` or `adb` for that matter, in the script; says *Unexpected Error*

Is it about adding a permanent reference to `adb` in `$PATH`. I am only doing it in a `bash_rc` file, which explains why the shell scripts (or things that open Terminal) run successfully - as they always call `bash_rc` first

If so, what is the way to do it?

Comment: you could try running adb by a full explicit path, found from 'which adb' in the terminal

Comment: This might be a lot easier to diagnose if you posted both the actual shell script and ctual error message.

Comment: @kopischke - Sorry for being so late... 1. Regarding actual error message, it says `adb: command not found`. 2. Regarding the script, I have an automator workflow that says Run Shell Script - `adb devices; adb install -r "$f"`, where `$f` is the list of files opened with the app. I am able to run other commands, for eg., putting the file paths to a txt file and most SH things as well

Comment: You are saying you are able to run `adb` from Automator services … how is it invoked there (not via a “Run Shell Script” action?

Comment: @kopischke, I am able to run **Other** commands in the Automator Workflow (Run Shell Scripts), but not `adb `. Thanks anyways, the full path technique worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following and it solved the problem:

```sh
export adb=path/to/adb

for f in "$@"
do
    $adb devices
    $adb do-something "$f"
done

# using adb devices; doesn't work as adb was not recognized, 
# so I exported it from full path

# $@ are my files that I wont to run my script upon
```